# How to add a SAVE button to replace PUBLISH on a custom post type?

Tags: metabox, publish

I have a custom post type called 'contacts'. I want want to remove the status, post date and change the button from PUBLISH to SAVE. From what I can tell this may not be possible without changing core files (please correct me if I am wrong).

So, instead of trying to hack the PUBLISH metabox, I have the ability to remove the PUBLISH meta box all together using the Access Manager plugin.  But I need to know how to readd a SAVE button that works the same way PUBLISH would.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean change it from "published" to "draft"?

Comment: No, since I am using this post type as a CONTACT, not as a POST, it does not make sense to say "PUBLISH" when saving. Plus, I don't want my users to see the other options that are in the PUBLISH metabox. So, the 'easiest' way of doing was to hid the PUBLISH metabox and add a new metabox with a SAVE button. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not mine but modified from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/change-the-text-on-the-publish-button).
But if you pop this into functions.php or a plugin it will work.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_publish_button', 10, 2 );

function change_publish_button( $translation, $text ) {
if ( 'yourcustomposttype' == get_post_type())
if ( $text == 'Publish' )
    return 'Save';

return $translation;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly to get the PUBLISH button to say SAVE - ty!

Comment: I believe it may be more efficient (and precise) if you enqueue a js file for that post type and then change the value of the submit input with jQuery, targeting only that specific button.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post, but I just cleaned up the code if anyone finds this thread via search like I did.

```
function change_publish_button( $translation, $text ) {
    if ( 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE' == get_post_type() && ($text == 'Publish' || $text == 'Update') ) {
        return 'Save';
    } else {
        return $translation;
    }
}
```