# How to add filter to __() and _e()?

Tags: filters

I would wish to add a filter to `_e()` and `__()` functions. The filter is **FilterTextOfEmail()**. This will basically detect any emails and add anti-spam method to it.

I assume, the function for filtering should look like:

```
function my_wp_text_email_filtering ($content) {
    return FilterTextOfEmail($content)
}
```

But how to call it?

Comment: Could you provide more context on what is you're trying to archieve? Is `FilterTextOfEmail` an example function name, or does that function literally exist? More details and clarification of the question please..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The filter name is `gettext`, and you would add it like this:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_wp_text_email_filtering', 10, 3 );

function my_wp_text_email_filtering( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    return FilterTextOfEmail( $translated );
}
```

The **$text** argument is there also in case you want to access the pre-translated text.

Comment: Thank you for answering, works great. However, what would be the filter for the `the_content()` as it appears, `__()` and `_e()` don't automatically apply for that.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here? You just want to apply the same filter to `the_content`? Wouldn't `add_filter( 'the_content', 'FilterTextOfEmail' );` work for that?

Answer (score 4):

You have to filter `'gettext'`. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/change-the-text-on-the-publish-button/3675#3675) for an example.

Always check the textdomain parameter to avoid conflicts with plugins and themes.