# How to remove 'create new post' entry for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I have a custom post type that is created using a form on the site.
I want to disable new post creation from wordpress admin.
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Look at my plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/

Comment: thanks, looked at the plugin, didn't think about the simple JS option :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways (depending on what you're trying to do):

#### If it's about the "publish" button

You could…

1. …remove the capability from the targeted role with [`remove_cap()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap)
2. …remove the [publish button <sup>1)</sup>](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3675/385)

   <sup>1) see bottom of the answer by @toscho</sup>
3. …or the [whole meta box <sup>2)</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box)

   ```
   remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'custom_post_id', 'side' );
   ```

   <sup>2) simplified version</sup>

#### If it's about the built in `post` post type

You could…

1. …simply hide the menu entry via css or js
2. …unset the menu entry with

   ```
   add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myprefix_adjust_the_wp_menu', 999 );
   function myprefix_adjust_the_wp_menu() {
     $page = remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'post-new.php' );
     //or for custom post type 'myposttype'.
     //$page = remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=myposttype', 'post-new.php?post_type=myposttype' );
   }
   ```
3. …prevent saving at all with the `per_save_post` hook and `$_GET['action']`
4. …do a redirect when the `post-new.php` is load

Answer (score 9):

There is a meta capability `create_posts` that is not documented but is used by WordPress to check before inserting the various 'Add New' buttons and links. In your custom post type declaration, add `capabilities` (not to be confused with `cap`) and then set it to `false` as below.

```
register_post_type( 'custom_post_type_name', array(
  'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => false,
  )
));
```

Comment: This has now changed to:
`
'capabilities' => [
 'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow'
],
'map_meta_cap' => true,
`

Answer (score 0):

@ hannit cohen,

This is best way to hide the Add New or Create New button in custom postypes

```
'capability_type'    => 'post',

        'capabilities'       => array( 'create_posts' => false ),       

        'map_meta_cap'       => true,
```

It disable to create new post in custom post types both side in admin menu and above the list of post type.