# contextual_help, change the "Help" tab label

Tags: contextual-help

Is there any way to change the "Help" tabs label? 
I speak about the top right tab to toggle the contextual help.

I'm looking to change "Help" label by "Documentation".

I work on WordPress 3.3 and 3.4 beta

Thanks for your advices

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the text on the Publish button](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/change-the-text-on-the-publish-button)

Comment: Well, it's not an _exact_ dublicate, but it answers **all** get text related questions just well.

Comment: Gilles, is not that you asked many questions, but I just stumbled upon wonderful (if not awesome) answers to most of your questions. Go for it and get rid of this big red **0%** that's under your signature :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/screen.php#L830), there is no filter to alter the 'Help'. But it does translate the text so you can hook onto the `gettext` filter. Not the nicest of solutions (an alternative would be to use javascript) :

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse51861_change_help_text', 10, 2 );

function wpse51861_change_help_text( $translation, $text ) {

if ( $text == 'Help' )
    return __('Documentation','my-plug-text-domain');

return $translation;
}
```