# Replace the "widgets" label in the backend

Tags: widgets

Is it possible to replace/modify the "Widgets" label in the backend by an other label ? ... and do the same thing for the "Widgets" title in the widget page.

Is there a filter or another solution ?

Comment: You could try "translating" it.

Comment: Yes it's a solution ... but I would rather avoid it if possible.

Comment: There are _many_ mentions of "widgets" in admin, please enumerate instances that you are looking to change.

Comment: @GillesVauvarin why?

Comment: @Rarst Appearance > Widgets and all the "Widgets" label in the widgets page setting.

Comment: That's a ton of different contexts... As for me - just use the translation filter, would be much more manageable.

Comment: Hey, hold on, are you gonna ask the [same Question over again](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/51861/12615) and **not accept any of the previous answers gaven to you**??? - Just deleting my answer to this one...

Comment: @brasolio You're right. I apologize. I never noticed the "accept" feature in WordPress Answer. I went back to my old questions to repair this mistake. Before to ask my (widget) questions, I checked my old questions and I didn't see the question you speak about. Now I understand why, I didn't see the "view more" link below my questions list. So again I apologize and I will buy a pair of glasses for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I used this solution to change the "Widgets" label in the sub-menu (Appearence > ...):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adjust_the_wp_menu', 999 );
function adjust_the_wp_menu() {
  $page = remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'widgets.php' );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');
function register_custom_menu_page() {
  add_submenu_page('themes.php', 'custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'add_users', 'widgets.php');
}`
```