# How to change "Draft" string for status of custom post type to "Unavailable"?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, actions, customization, post-status

**ANSWER MOD**: just an important mod to the chosen answer:

```
// check if you actually have drafts; also avoids extra '|' separator
if (isset($views['draft'])) {
    // 'Drafts' should be added (and come first) if you don't want to end up with 'Unavailables'
    $views['draft'] = str_replace(array('Drafts','Draft'), 'Unavailable', $views['draft']);
}
```

and the mentioned caveat is not showing up for me on 3.4. :D

---

Only for one particular custom post type `employee`, I want to change the name/string "Draft" (which stands for the `'draft'` status) to "Unavailable" for any `employee` post that has a `'draft'` status, anywhere the name shows up on the admin screens and basically throughout the entire site, i.e.

[image]

Is there a hook for this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at register_post_status function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_status but it's not enough in your case.

Comment: hm.. thanks, @EugeneManuilov will look into that for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was investigating the issue for [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/55136/12615), and one option is using the plugin [Edit Flow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-flow/).

It can be configured to display custom `post_status` in specific CPT's, but further tests are necessary to see if it applies to this case.

---

Other option is using toscho's Retranslate plugin, where you can define the string to be translated and the `post_type`: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3675/12615

It gets almost all the job done, because, curiously, there's one string <sup>(the very first one of the screenshot)</sup> that don't gets translated and one extra code is necessary:

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-employee', 'wpse_54330_custom_draft_translation', 10, 1);

function wpse_54330_custom_draft_translation( $views ) 
{
    $views['draft'] = str_replace('Draft', 'Unavailable', $views['draft']);
    return $views;
}
```

One caveat of this method is that just after "quick editing" the post status, the word *Draft* appears...

Comment: interesting, will defs work on this and get back to you. am also lookin into the `gettext` filter with a conditional for the post type. will post what i end up doing once i've sorted it out. thanks @brasofilo

Comment: that is, if those "Draft" strings are passed on to gettext..

Comment: this is actually working mighty fine fo'me! no such caveat on wp3.4. thanks much you epic you... lol! just had to insert `'Drafts'` in there, see my question edit. :D