# Renaming profile sections

Tags: profiles

wondering if anyone can help, i need to change the name of the sections on the user profile page (the name, contact info titles) etc

I know how to change the fields via a functions plugin but can't figure out the section names.

Ideally I'd prefer to do it via functions plugin than editing core files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the "plugin/functions.php" issue, see: [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615)

You can use the following modified version from [toscho's Retranslate Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3675/12615). I changed `post_type` for `pagenow`. Configure the translations in the final array.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Retranslate Profile Page
Description: Adds translations.
Version:     0.1b
Author:      Thomas Scholz
Author URI:  http://toscho.de
License:     GPL v2
*/
class Toscho_Retrans {
    // store the options
    protected $params;

    /**
     * Set up basic information
     * 
     * @param  array $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct( array $options ) {
        $defaults = array (
            'domain'       => 'default'
        ,   'context'      => 'backend'
        ,   'replacements' => array()
        ,   'pagenow'      => array()
        );

        $this->params = array_merge( $defaults, $options );

        // When to add the filter
        $hook = 'backend' == $this->params['context'] 
            ? 'admin_head' : 'template_redirect';

        add_action( $hook, array ( $this, 'register_filter' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Conatiner for add_filter()
     * @return void
     */
    public function register_filter() {
        add_filter( 'gettext', array ( $this, 'translate' ), 10, 3 );
    }

    /**
     * The real working code.
     * 
     * @param  string $translated
     * @param  string $original
     * @param  string $domain
     * @return string
     */
    public function translate( $translated, $original, $domain ) {
        // exit early
        if ( 'backend' == $this->params['context'] ) {
            global $pagenow;

            if ( ! empty ( $pagenow ) 
                && ! in_array( $pagenow, $this->params['pagenow'] ) )
            {
                return $translated;
            }
        }

        if ( $this->params['domain'] !== $domain ) {
            return $translated;
        }

        // Finally replace
        return strtr( $original, $this->params['replacements'] );
    }
}

// Sample code
// Replace 'Name' and 'Personal Options' on the profile page
$Toscho_Retrans = new Toscho_Retrans(
    array (
        'replacements' => array ( 
            'Name' => 'The Name'
        ,   'Personal Options' => 'The Options'
        ,   'Something Else' => 'Lorem Ipsum'
        )
    ,   'pagenow'    => array ( 'profile.php', 'edit-user.php' )
    )
);
```

Another option is to use jQuery:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'rename_profile_h3' );

function rename_profile_h3()
{ 
    global $pagenow;
    if( !in_array( $pagenow, array('profile.php', 'edit-user.php') ) )
      return;
    ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#your-profile").find("h3:contains('Name')").text('The Name');
    $("#your-profile").find("h3:contains('Personal Options')").text('The Options');
});
</script>
    <?php
}
```

Both examples are running in the admin pages Profile and User Edit.