# Change the "Allow comments" text for admin edit screen for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, comments-template

I have a custom post type that uses an alternative comments template. I modified the comments template for my custom post type to function like a five star review system.

Is there a way I can change the "Allow comments" on the edit screen for my custom post type to read "Allow reviews"?

[image: screenshot of edit screen for custom post type]

Answer (score 0):

You can fire filter hook [`gettext` ( example available too )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) to change default text **Allow comments.** in admin edit screen. Here another sample function:

```
add_filter( 'gettext','wpse221235_change_admin_cpt_text_filter', 1, 3 );
function wpse221235_change_admin_cpt_text_filter( $translated_text, $text, $domain )
{
    global $typenow;

    if ( is_admin() && 'Allow comments.' == $text && 'your-post-type' == $typenow )
        $translated_text = __( 'Allow reviews.', 'text_domain' );

    return $translated_text;
}
```

Of course, thanks @Sumit for point out, those sample just give the OP the direction, the same approach with WordPress example. If we need a more generic approach, please visit [@toscho answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3675/18731), there are a lot of discussion about it, and we can figure out the good approach to change text translation.

Comment: I think `is_admin()` and `$typenow` should be checked before adding the action! This filter will be active everywhere now!

Comment: @paul-coppock you're welcome. Good luck with your project.